# jquery post, json invalid label

Tags: php, jquery, json

Hello im try to use post in jquery to read data from my php file, and export it to js script as json object.

But I have a problem... Im using firebug console, and i have a error: invalid label...

It is my PHP code:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abonenci WHERE $where");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
json_encode($row);
```

And it is my jquery code:

```
$.post("ajax/domeny_abonenci.php", { pesel: get_pesel, nip: get_nip },
function(data){
    alert(data.nip);
}, "json");
```

Comment: What's the line of JS that it says has the error?

Comment: hmm all lines... i try to do test and type json_encode(array('error'=>'its only test'));

And firebug say this same... ant point arrow on error label...
I try to change labels but i dont see any changes...

Comment: Have you tried alerting the whole `data` object to check what it contains? You could start the debuging there.

Comment: i try to do this in php...

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Podany numer nie istnieje w bazie'));

In post function i add alert(data.error);
And its not wotking..

Comment: just do `console.log(data);` or ` `alert(data);` and tell whether the alert ever fires or not if it fires what does it say

Comment: Alert dont working... CODE:

$.post("ajax/domeny_abonenci.php", { pesel: get_pesel, nip: get_nip },
      function(data){
        alert(data);
      }, "json");

Comment: I change my jquery lib... And its works now lol...

Answer (score 0):

Are your HTTP headers set to json?

```
 <?php
 header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote your DATA:

```
{ "pesel": "get_pesel", "nip": "get_nip" }
```

Comment: Are you sure PHP is writing a well formatted JSON response? show us your PHP code.

Comment: <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Podany numer nie istnieje w bazie'));
?>

Comment: ok, so you should have alert(data.error) instead of data.nip.

Answer (score 0):

Add "(" before and ")" and end of data. This should solve the problem.

Refer this link:

http://willcode4beer.com/tips.jsp?set=jsonInvalidLabel

p.s. You need to put '(' and ')'. Sorry, I was out of my mind to type '{' '}' . I have fixed now.

Comment: sorrry, i dont understand you mean:
$.post("ajax/domeny_abonenci.php", { "pesel: get_pesel, nip: get_nip" } ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you echoing the encoded json data?

Anyway, in your PHP file, try ending with:

```
echo "(".json_encode($row).")";
exit;
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the Post Function is a success function(data,textStatus) what ocurrs AFTER we have send the Post form. In this function, "data" returns the success post, and "textStatus" returns the final ajax status. I believe that you haven't a NIP parameter in your response really, so data.nip is undefined.